Show angle between two vectors in term of their respective direction cosines
Vectors $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ have directions cosines $l_1$, $m_1$ and $n_1$ and $l_2$, $m_2$ and $n_2$ respectively. Verify if the angle between $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ is $$\cos{ \rm{\theta}} = \left|l_{1}l_{2}+ m_{1}m_{2} + n_{1}n_{2} \right|  $$
Is the above expression true? I feel it is not.
This is my partial attempt, assuming that the above expression is true:
So we know that angle between two vectors can be shown in terms of their dot product and cosine. So we get $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |a||b| \cos{\theta}$
And we know that $l = |r| \cos{\alpha}$, where $|r|$ is the magnitude of vector, $l$ is of course the direction consine, and $\cos{\alpha}$ is the cosine of the vector with respect to the x-axis,
What’s the next step?
